# In Common Lisp FORMAT how does recursive formatting work

Tags: format, common-lisp

I need to generate a space-padded string with a variable string length. The not-so-clever solution that works involved nesting of `format`:

```
(format nil (format nil "~~~d,,a" 10) "asdf")
```

Now, I wanted to make it a bit more clever by using `format`'s `~?` for recursive processing. I would expect that something like this should do what I want:

```
(format nil "~@?" "~~~d,,a" 10 "asdf")
```

but what I get is just the formatting string, i.e. `~10,,a`, not the padded `asdf` string. Perhaps I misunderstood the word 'recursive' here, but I would expect that having formed the inner format string, CL should proceed to actually use it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use `v` in the control string: `(format nil "~va" 10 "asdf")`

Comment: Cool, thanks. This solves my particular case. But it got me thinking about a trickier use. Say, you not only want to parameterize the amount of padding, but also what you're padding with and you'd like to arrive at a formatting string of this form: `(format nil  "~10,,,'-a" "asdf")`. Any chance of achieving it  using `~?`??

Comment: `(format nil "~v,,,va" 10 #\- "asdf")`

Comment: You can have multiple `v`s: `(format nil "~v,,,va" 10 #\- "asdf")`. You misunderstand the use case for `~?`. It's mainly meant for inserting another "call" to format with a different control string and arguments in a control string. For example, to prompt for a yes or no, you might have a function like `(defun y-or-n-prompt (control-string &rest args) (format t "~&~? [y/n]: " control-string args))`

Comment: @jkiiski I see. My impression was that apart from formatting a substring recursively, `format` also processes this substring.

Comment: Generally, building control strings for `FORMAT` at run time is a bad idea. It's error prone and if you use a constant control string, implementations may process it at compile time rather than run time (producing more efficient code).

Comment: @jkiiski : looks like this is worth an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Variable arguments to format directives**

`FORMAT` allows you to use `v` as an argument to a directive in the control string to pop arguments from the argument list.

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~va" 10 "asdf")
"asdf      "
```

There may be multiple `v`s used.

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~v,,,va" 10 #\- "asdf")
"asdf------"
```

**Recursive processing with `~?`**

The recursive processing directive is meant for embedding a different "call" to `FORMAT` inside a control string. For example, a function to prompt for a yes or no answer might be implemented with it.

```
(defun y-or-n-prompt (control-string &rest args)
  (format t "~&~? [y/n]: " control-string args)
  ;;...
  )
```

The caller can now format a prompt with this as they would with `FORMAT` without having to worry about the details of what the prompt should look like to the user (adding a new line at the beginning or the `[y/n]:` prompt at the end).

```
CL-USER> (y-or-n-prompt "foo ~d bar" 12)
foo 12 bar [y/n]: 
NIL
```

The result of `~?` will not be processed by `FORMAT`, so it cannot be used to build a control string. In general, building control strings at run time is a bad idea, because it's error prone (for example, you must escape any unwanted tildes in the string) and prevents the implementation from processing the control string at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for and exhaustive answer.

Comment: *(...) and prevents the implementation from processing the control string at compile time.* – This is true for any dynamic format string, whether you use the `~?` recursive directive or `format` itself.  But the user still has the option to compile a format string to a format control at runtime with [`formatter`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_format.htm), and decide to cache it at will.