# Nicer pythonic `join` in common-lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, metaprogramming

In Edi Weitz's cl cookbook, for the pythonic `join`, this function is suggested:

```
(defun join (separator list)
  (with-output-to-string (out)
    (loop for (element . more) on list
          do (princ element out)
          when more
            do (princ separator out))))
```

However, somehow I was thinking, there must be a way to express `join` in another way, maybe using `format`'s capabilities ...

In Seibel's book, (in the chapter about `format`) we find joining of strings in a list to a single string with the separator 
`", "` by:

```
(defvar l '("a" "b" "c"))

(format nil "~{~A~^, ~}" l)
;; "a, b, c"
```

Which is a pythonic join and which is very terse; the `~^` directive makes that `", "` is added only until just before the last element and not added when no element is following.

However, here, the separator string `", "` is part of the format directive.

A tricky case is e.g. `(defvar sep #\Tab)`.
If the representation of sep `"#\Tab"` literally can be placed as a separator in midst of this format directive, resulting in:

```
(format nil "~{~A~^#\Tab~}" l)
```

We would have reached the goal.

Obviously, one has to use a macro to generate the format directive ...
I tried things like `(princ-to-string sep)` but this gives `"#\\Tab"` and not `"#\Tab"`.

E.g.

```
(defmacro join (sep l)
  `(format nil ,(format nil "~{~A~}" `("\~\{\~A\~\^" ,(write-to-string sep) "\~\}")) l))
```

But when trying:

```
(join #\Tab '("a" "b" "c"))
```

This results of course is sth not desired: `"a#\\Tabb#\\Tabc"`, since

```
(macroexpand-1 '(join #\Tab '("a" "b" "c")))
;; results in:
(FORMAT NIL "~{~A~^#\\Tab~}" L)
;; instead of:
(FORMAT NIL "~{~A~^#\Tab~}" L)
```

But I don't see how to achieve this step to the desired macro ...
Has anybody an enlightening about this?

Kind of a metaprogramming on metaprogramming problem ...

Okay, now I see, that @Rainer Joswig has already posted in
[What's the canonical way to join strings in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830888/whats-the-canonical-way-to-join-strings-in-a-list)

a solution to this problem. However, if there would be a way, to represent `"#\\Tab"` as `"#\Tab"`, one could come to a more compact definition.
But somehow the Lisp reader seems in a string always to recognize `"\Tab"` as one letter. Is it possible to write a function to do that?

**Remark**

In R, there exist especially for metaprogramming, functions like `as.name("myvar")` which generate the symbol`myvar` out of the string "myvar".
and expressions like `deparse(substitute(x))` which takes the symbol `x` and creates out of it a literal string `"x"`. Deparse steps back the execution of `print()` commands, whereby escaping special symbols. `deparse(deparse(substitute(x)))` would e.g. generate `"\"x\""` - While `parse(text = ... )` around this expression would make out of it `"x"` again `parse(text = deparse(deparse(substitute(x))))`. 
How such things could be achived in common-lisp? 
e.g.`(a-special-function #\Tab)` resulting in (literal): `"#\Tab"` as a string?

**Epilogue**

Thank you @Sylwester!! He solved it without macro. And very elegantly!

Comment: `(char-name #\Tab) ;; => "Tab"` ? Also `(symbol-name 'foo) ;; => "FOO"`.

Comment: Might like: how to use variables in format's control strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868555/in-common-lisp-format-how-does-recursive-formatting-work

Comment: You might like [str:join](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/#join-separator-list-of-strings), but it doesn't accept a character as separator (disclaimer: author of this simple lib).

Comment: You might want to use cl-interpol:https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102882/124319 and do `(format nil #?"~{~a~^$(separator)~}" '(a b c d))` where `separator` is lexically bound around the call.

Comment: @coredump: Yes! Exactly sth like that I was searching! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to add `#\Tab` to the format, but that is just how you do it with literals. If you just inserted a tab character or a string consisting of it in the format string it will do what you want:

```
(defun join (l &key (sep ", "))
  (format nil (format nil "~a~a~a" "~{~a~^" sep "~}") l))

(join '(1 2 3)) 
; ==> "1, 2, 3"
(join '(1 2 3) :sep #\Tab) 
; ==> "1    2   3"
```

Comment: Oh thank you!!! I was trying along for over an hour .... Thank you so much! That is exactly I wanted to do! So easy actually ... That is the super elegantly short `join` I was searching for!

Comment: Very elegant the solution to do `"~a~a~a"` first and then give the single parts of the string ... - no mess with escape characters - so nice!

Comment: Shortly I was loosing my faith in Lisp - that it is the best language ever - since couldn't do such an easy thing with the terseness which one is used to with Lisp - *now* its elegance shines again - Thank you @Sylwester!