# Use variable padding in iteration directive in FORMAT

Tags: format, common-lisp

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
(format t "~{~va~}" '("aa" "bb" "cc") 4)
```

I need to iterate through a list. Each element of that list should be padded with a variable number of spaces (specified at runtime, so I cannot use "~4a").

Or more generally, is there a way to refer to a specific argument in the argument list of FORMAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By nesting `format` function, you can do what you want.

```
(format t (format nil "~~{~~~Aa~~}" 4) '("aa" "bb" "cc"))
;; returns: aa  bb  cc
```

Here the inner `format` directive:
The `nil` as first argument, `format` returns a string.

```
(format nil "~~{~~~Aa~~}" 4)
;; returns: "~{~4a~}" - and this is exactly what you want to give
;; to the outer `format` as second argument!
```

You can of course write a function for this:

```
(defun format-by-padding-over (lst padding)
  (format t (format nil "~~{~~~Aa~~}" padding) lst))
```

And then:

```
(format-by-padding-over '("aa" "bb" "cc") 4)
;; aa  bb  cc  
;; NIL
```

I learned this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647635/nicer-pythonic-join-in-common-lisp) from @Sylwester (many thanks!).

Answer (score 0):

You could also interleave the list with repetitions of the padding:

```
(format t "~{~va~}"
        (mapcan (lambda (element)
                  (list 4 element))
                list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build the format control string using nested format functions, but then you have to take care about escaping tildes. When working with regular expressions (using CL-PPCRE), one can define regular expressions using trees, like `(:alternation #\\ #\*)`, which helps preventing bugs and headaches related to escaping special characters. The same can be done with format strings, using `format-string-builder`, available in Quicklisp:

```
(lambda (v)
  (make-format-string `((:map () (:str ,v)))))
```

Returns a closure, which can be used to build format strings:

```
(funcall * 10)
=> "~{~10a~}"
```